# How to use different preamble in subfiles root file and child file

Tags: subfiles

I have both `\maketitle \tableofcontents` in the root file and child file when using `subfiles` package. When I compiling the child file, it works OK. But when I compiling the root file, the `title` and `author` information and an extra 'Content' are also appeared. I do not know how to erase these informations.

I tried to use macros to control the actions. But it does not work very well.

I have several puzzles.

1.Does the new definition of the variable in child file erased its value transfered from root file?

2.Is there a command to test if a variable  here like `multiple` has already been difnied?

3.When debugging latex, how to output the value you definied in latex?

4.Are there any other graceful ways to achieve my aim?

Thank you!

Here is the root file named root.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\newif\ifmultiple  %\multipletrue means called by main file
\multipletrue

\author{Ct586}
\title{How to use subfiles}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\subfile{child}

\end{document}
```

Here is the child file named child.tex:

```
\documentclass[Dynamic.Network.Embryonic.Development.tex]{subfiles}

\newif\ifmultiple  %\multipletrue means called by main file
%\multipletrue
\ifmultiple
    \begin{document}
\else
    \author{Ct586}
    \title{How to use subfiles}
    \date{\today}
    \begin{document}
      \maketitle    
      \tableofcontents
\fi


\section{child}
child

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may find Martin Scharrer's [`standalone package`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) useful. The package is more recent and actively maintained.

Comment: `standalone` looks very powerful. Thank you. I will try to use it. And also I wonder how to make my way, setting a variable, work?

Comment: `verbatim` package has a `comment` environment which will allow you to configure your document according to whether it is called from the master or not. I'm sorry I can't give you a proper answer, but I'm completely overwhelmed by stuff at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `\let\tableofcontents\relax` after the main one:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{child.tex}
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
    \author{Ct586}
    \title{How to use subfiles}
    \date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle    
\tableofcontents

\section{child}
child

\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\author{Ct586}
\title{How to use subfiles}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\def\author#1{} \def\title#1{}
\tableofcontents
\let\tableofcontents\relax

\subfile{child}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `\let\tableofcontents\relax` worked well. The word 'Content' disappeared. I save two files named 'main.tex' and 'child.tex'. When I am compiling 'child.tex', get `LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./child.tex'.`. When I am compiling 'main.tex', the `author` and `title` information of `child.tex` still exist. So what is the question? Thank you!

Comment: Insert `\def\author#1{}
\def\title#1{}` just rightafter the `\maketitle` in `main.tex`. See my edited answer